# awk on date conditions

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I am trying delete rows from a person.csv (below) for the condition that person who are not born in last 1 year:

*Dataset1*:

```
"Index","User Id","First Name","Last Name","Date of birth","Job Title"
"1","9E39Bfc4fdcc44e","new, Diamond","Dudley","06 Dec 1945","Photographer"
"3","32C079F2Bad7e6F","Ethan","Hanson","08 Mar 2014","Actuary"
"2","aaaaaaa, bbbbbb","Grace","Huerta","21 Jan 2023","Visual merchandiser"
```

So, the expected output would look like(last row got deleted as born in less than one year):

```
"Index","User Id","First Name","Last Name","Date of birth","Job Title"
"1","9E39Bfc4fdcc44e","new, Diamond","Dudley","06 Dec 1945","Photographer"
"3","32C079F2Bad7e6F","Ethan","Hanson","08 Mar 2014","Actuary"
```

I tried to use awk for this something like :

```
awk -F , '{print $5 ....}' person.csv > output.csv
```

But, couldn't figure out how to compare the each row date with (today minus 1 year).

*Dataset2*: Sometimes it is possible to have double quotes inside double quoted field e.g.(line1 field4):

```
"Index","User Id","First Name","Last Name","Date of birth","Job Title"
"1","9E39Bfc4fdcc44e","new, Diamond","Dudley (aka "dud")","03 Oct 2023","Photographer"
"3","32C079F2Bad7e6F","Ethan","Hanson","03 Dec 2022","Actuary"
"2","aaaaaaa, bbbbbb","Grace","Huerta","21 Jan 2023","Visual merchandiser"
```

I am open for 'sed' too if that can do this.
Any help please, thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be awk or sed? This literally is like a handful lines of Python, which has mature Datetime parsing, safe quoted-text CSV reading, and is available on almost any system you are likely to use these days?

Comment: Perl can handle dates just fine.

Comment: or that! Whatever you're comfortable with, but seeing OP is asking a basic question about awk or sed (which itself is wholly unsuitable), they selected tools that they neither understand nor that are highly suitable for the task at hand. (I think awk might work, but my awk-foo isn't good enough).

Comment: Also, what is `29  Feb 2020` minus one year?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes I definitely agree with you on using Python for this, but on our server we don't have its pandas etc. installed, and surely it will take longer to get those installed. I was able to do it in my personal pc using pythons though. But I am stuck with awk, sed etc. for now or perl if it doesn't require some non default lib

Comment: by minus one year I mean some hypothetical condition, in this case, it simply means -365 days (but of course could be -7 days or etc.)

Comment: setting aside the discussion about leap years and how many days are in a year ... it would help if we know which versions of software you have available; for example, at the command line prompt does `date -d '-1 year' '+%d %b %Y'` work on your system to generate a date from 1 year ago (eg, `16 Sep 2022`)? also, what does `awk --version` generate?

Comment: about the csv file format ... will all columns/fields be guaranteed to be wrapped in double quotes? can any of the fields have double quotes as part of the data (ie, embedded or escaped double quotes)?

Comment: No need for pandas at all. Stock python does this fairly well.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, really? would you be able to enlighten a bit please? I had done using pandas.

Comment: @markp-fuso - yes, based on my dataset review I can safely say that the external system that generated this file has forced double quotes for every field(with no embedded double quotes in any field). and each double quoted field is separated by  a comma, however, embedded comma is possible in any double quoted field e.g. 2nd field of 3line in my question : "aaaaaaa, bbbbbb"

Comment: @markp-fuso, yes leap year etc. is not a concern in my case - I can live with simply subtracting 1 year(365 days)/ 7 days etc. And yes date -d '-1 year' '+%d %b %Y' generates as you mentioned 16 Sep 2022. And awk --version says : GNU Awk 4.2.1, API 2.0 lablalba

Comment: @zoomer stock python brings both the `csv` library to read and write CSV files, as well as the `datetime` library to read dates from strings (` datetime.datetime.strptime`), deal with dates, and differences between dates.

Comment: Is there any possibility to fix the source of the CSV so it generates ISO dates (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Comment: @Barmar: That was my first thought when I realized that I have to deal with unusual date format. But, sorry, that change we can't force to the external system owners, their data is used by many other clients too and not sure, who made the initial decision to do that.

Comment: First, having witnessed both of the magical answers, I really really wish to be able to select multiple answers as ACCEPTED, but I think it's not possible. Just two cents: I think I will be fool(which I am, without doubt), if I talk about performance while using these command line tools. Perhaps scope of these tools are oriented towards getting jobs done without writing up a separate traditional program/apps. If I had to consider the performance I should have chosen python etc. in the first place, but due to things out of my control I couldn't afford to do that..continued...

Comment: ...continued...having said that, i do want to mention that for my dataset (100k), took about 5min(forgive me please to compare at minute level) vs 8 seconds, which ofcourse is undoubtedly uncomparable [another test of 1000k : 57min vs 8seconds (still 8 seconds, unbelievable!! --not sure how come constant time, anyway, that's what really happened)]. Also, with me  at medium level of friendliness with awk, and could understood both solution, honestly, 1st one was easier for my average brain, where I had to scratch my head few times for the 2nd. But, yeah nothing comes without cost.

Comment: Also, I am amazed to see such great helpers!!!! who can make me kick out those guys who lecture me to do a whole new app in some new modern language etc.(without any concrete directions), where you guys can do the same by just oneliner!!! and with just standard tools (no extra tool/lib)

Comment: @zoomer  you can upvote/downvote multiple answers; 'accept'ing an answer is limited to just one answer; see this [note about (un)accepting answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @zoomer 8 seconds sounds a bit high but this could be due to your older version of `awk` and/or (more likely?) a performance hit from the disks underlying your filesystem (or even some network overhead if working on an NFS-mounted disk); the fact that you get the same 8 seconds (100K vs 1000K) sounds more like a system issue (eg, disk) than a coding issue (ie, for this (relatively) simple task an efficient `awk` script isn't going to break much of a sweat going from 100K to 1000K)

Comment: I am afraid to say that after looking too much in large dataset, I noticed it is sometimes possible to have double quotes within double quoted field .e.g. one field value: "abc def   (aka "xyz") " . And for this, 1st solution seems to be working without any change. 2nd one, I tried with the FPAT version of the solution, but I think it needs some tweaking...I will update my question to reflect this case.

Comment: Note that your last edit makes your data an improperly quoted CSV data set.  If a field is to contain the text `Dudley (aka "dud")` it must be quoted as `"Dudley (aka ""dud"")"`.  If it isn't, it's no longer proper CSV and some parsers may have difficulty reading it correctly.  Fortunately, the second half of my answer still seems to be able to cope with it.

Comment: with your latest data update (`"Dudley (aka "dud")"`) the 2nd half of my answer (the one using `FPAT`) prints the first 3 lines (header, Index = 1/3) as expected; please update the question with a sample row of data that causes problems and state what the problem is (row should be printed but is not; row is printed but should be skipped)

Comment: @markp-fuso I have just updated the date of birth in the Dataset2. Now, all 3 date of births are after the cutoff( of last 1 year), so expecting the output should be empty(just header). Can you please check once?

Comment: @zoomer fixed; with the new set of data my `FPAT` answer only prints the header; let me know if you run into any other issues

Comment: @markp-fuso - yeah, logically it works great now. I can see no data line in output and some data line depending on date of birth if older than cutoff. So both ways good. only that the formatting is little different now(commas, got replaced by space and date is without quotes now - I think due to substitution) in case of data line is printed. Anyway, thanks a ton for perseverance!

Comment: @zoomer ok, another patch applied to the `FPAT` answer

Comment: zoomer please note @Kusalananda's very important point [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756720/awk-on-date-conditions#comment1441593_756720) - a field like `"abc def (aka "xyz") "` is not valid CSV by any "standard", quotes inside a quoted field MUST be escaped in some way, either by doubling `"abc def (aka ""xyz"") "` per the RFC or, far less commonly and not part of the RFC, by escaping `"abc def (aka \"xyz\") "` so you must treat any answer you get with a large pinch of salt and do extensive testing of rainy-day cases if your input really does have fields like that.

Comment: And, most importantly, fix whatever tool is generating "CSV"-like files like that as no tool can  tell if `"foo","bar"` is one field containing 2 double quotes and a comma or 2 fields separated by a comma (unless you then tell us that quoted fields cannot contain commas, which would be another departure from any CSV "standard" as commas in fields are why we quote them).

Comment: @Ed Thanks for reiterating the point about the well formed CSV. I (and of course anybody else) agree without a second thought. Currently, both the solutions shared by both great humans are able to get the job done amazingly without any additional tool. I don't have enough words to thank them. I am still looking out for possible edge cases, but may be that's for little later. I also Thank Kusalananda for the solution and suggestion on the formatting. I will try it out. For fixing the CSV source system(possibly proprietary) I don't have that luxury and I am yet to give enough motivation to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and GNU [date](/questions/tagged/date) and 1 year condition:

```
awk -v epoch1y=$(date -d '1 year ago' +%s) '
    BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}
    NR>1{
        cmd="date -d " $5 " +%s"
        epoch=( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A")
        close(cmd)
        if (epoch > epoch1y) next
    }
    1
' person.csv
```

#### Output

```
"Index","User Id","First Name","Last Name","Date of birth","Job Title"
"1","9E39Bfc4fdcc44e","new, Diamond","Dudley","06 Dec 1945","Photographer"
"3","32C079F2Bad7e6F","Ethan","Hanson","08 Mar 2014","Actuary"
```

#### Explanations

the code should be clear, concise and quite readable.

The not obvious part, is the use of `FPAT` special variable ([*splitting by content*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)), to be able to handle more use cases than a simple `-F,`:

> [image: note] Some programs export CSV data that contains embedded newlines between the double quotes. gawk provides no way to deal with this. Even though a formal specification for CSV data exists, there isn’t much more to be done; **the FPAT mechanism provides an elegant solution for the majority of cases**, and the gawk developers are satisfied with that.

---

The `getline` part is a trick from `awk` to run shell command and feed the variable after `getline`.

---

`1` at the end, means `true`, so on a `true` condition, by default, it means `print` current line.

---

Doc about `close()` call: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html

---

`epoch` is Unix timestamp: number of seconds since `1/1/1970`.

Comment: @Gilles - you are awesome!! - it worked great for the dataset I posted in the question! But.... it seems it could process 2087 lines only on my real dataset(around 100k lines). Error I got is :    awk: cmd. line4:(FILENAME=person.csv FNR=2087) fatal: cannot open pipe `date -d "27 Jul 2004" +%s' (Too many open files).     Would you be able to suggest on this. Worst case, I can make multiple smaller files (100k lines -> 2k lines), but hoping for any better idea. Please help!

Comment: @zoomer: Show output of `ulimit -n`.

Comment: @Cyrus it is : `1024`. I also randomly checked about 10 other servers(new/old, physical/cloud, prod/non-prod). 9 out of 10, had the same `1024` value. Only one had `8096`. Based on this, it doesn't look weirdly low set. Anyway, if this is the issue then even increasing it little bit (which of course will be time taking procedure to follow) I am not sure if that can help, when my dataset contains 100k+ lines, right? I am not sure if we could somehow close files mentioned(not sure if it opens for each line) in the solution, before proceeding to next line...

Comment: @GillesQuénot My OS is RHEL8.     awk --version says : GNU Awk 4.2.1, API 2.0 lablalba ..  I tested with 2088 lines - it failed. Then I tested with 2086 lines - worked great.

Comment: @GillesQuénot, wow, what a magic! it didn't break this time!!! it ran well! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Already had upvoted. Accepted too! Thanks again!

Comment: @zoomer regardless of the `ulimit` setting, making 100K system calls (from `awk`) to `date` *plus* the associated overhead of 100K file descriptor opens/closes means a big hit on performance; I've updated my answer with a performance comparison of the two answers

Answer (score 5):

Assumptions:

- all columns/fields are wrapped in double quotes
- double quotes do not show up as part of the data (otherwise we'll need something other than a basic `-F'"'` as a field separator)
- OP's (OS) `date` supports the `-d` argument (eg, if 'today' is `16 Sep 2023` then on OP's system `date -d '-1 year' '+%Y%m%d'` will generate `20220916`)
- since OP has mentioned the cutoff date could be anything (eg, -1 year, -7 days, etc) we'll use the (OS) `date` to generate the cutoff date in `YYYYMMDD` format (otherwise we need to add a bit more code to `awk` to be able to handle various conditions like '-1 year', '-7 days', etc)

One `awk` approach:

```
cutoff=$(date -d '-1 year' '+%Y%m%d')                             # change '-1 year' to the desired condition;
                                                                  # alternatively: manually set to the desired date (in YYYYMMDD format)

awk -v cutoff="${cutoff}" -F'"' '                                 # set awk variable "cutoff" to the value of the OS variable of the same name
                                                                  # field delimiter is double quotes; this means data fields are even-numbered (eg, 5th field is the 10th "-delimited field)
BEGIN { mlist="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec" }
NR>1  { split($10,a,/[[:space:]]+/)                               # split 5th data field on spaces; a[1]=day a[2]=month a[3]=year
        m=sprintf("%02d", ( (index(mlist,a[2])+2) /3) )           # convert 3-letter month to 2-digit month
        if ( a[3] m a[1] > cutoff) next                           # if new date is greater than the cutoff then skip to the next line of input
      } 
1                                                                 # print the current line
' person.csv
```

This generates:

```
"Index","User Id","First Name","Last Name","Date of birth","Job Title"
"1","9E39Bfc4fdcc44e","new, Diamond","Dudley","06 Dec 1945","Photographer"
"3","32C079F2Bad7e6F","Ethan","Hanson","08 Mar 2014","Actuary"
```

---

Performance perspective ...

This answer requires a single OS call to `date` and requires 1 file descriptor open/close (2 if you redirect the output to another file).

Gilles' answer requires an OS call to `date` for each line of input *and* requires the costly overhead of opening/closing a file descriptor for each `date` call.

Test run:

```
100K line file          # per comment from OP
GNU awk 5.1.0
GNU date 8.32
Ubuntu 20.04
i7-1260P
```

This answer:

```
real    0m0.198s        <<< 546 times faster
user    0m0.198s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Gilles' answer:

```
real    1m48.229s       <<<
user    1m30.598s
sys     0m23.999s
```

Output from both runs were saved to files; a `diff` of the two output files showed no differences (ie, both answers generate the same result set).

---

In this case OP has stated that all fields are wrapped in double quotes.

In the case where some fields may not be wrapped in double quotes we can make use of `GNU awk's 'FPAT'` and still only perform the single call to `date`, eg:

```
cutoff=$(date -d '-1 year' '+%Y%m%d')

awk -v cutoff="${cutoff}" '
BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
        mlist="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"
      }
NR>1  { f5=$5
        gsub(/"/,"",f5)                                           # strip double quotes from 5th data field
        split(f5,a,/[[:space:]]+/)                                # change from 10th field to 5th field
        m=sprintf("%02d", ( (index(mlist,a[2])+2) /3) )
        if ( a[3] m a[1] > cutoff) next
      }
    1
' person.csv
```

Using the same test criteria as above, this answer's run time:

```
real    0m0.861s        <<<
user    0m0.850s
sys     0m0.009s
```

Parsing the input based on `FPAT` (as opposed to `-F'"'`) increases run time by ~4x but it's still considerably faster than 108 seconds.

Comment: You are wonderful!! it worked great on the dataset I posted in the question as well as on my real dataset(100k lines)! Just that the logic of 3-letter month to 2-digit month had issue and it took me some to figure out that I think it should have been a[2] (not a[3]).. Apart from this fix, it worked like a charm! Many Thanks!

Comment: @zoomer *arg* ...  typo on my behalf; answer's been updated so the index is based on `a[2]` (instead of `a[3]`)

Comment: even with the typo, solution gave me directions @markp. Much appreciated! I surely wish to accept both the answers.

Comment: You won some milliseconds, well, but readability should be privileged sometimes when  gaining fast execution is not _that_ important.

Comment: @GillesQuénot yeah, only ~108,000 *milliseconds*; as for readability ... anyone with some basic understanding of `awk` should have no problems reading/understanding both answers

Comment: Also consider re-usability too, my answer gave a universal re-usable solution. Yours is a bit specific and not that re-usable for next readers with slightly changes

Comment: I'll take performance (here: 0.2 secs vs 108.2 secs; OP's comments: 8secs vs 5mins, 8secs vs 57mins) over *re-usability* every time

Answer (score 0):

Since `awk` does not know about the quoting rules of CSV, it would be better to use a CSV-aware tool for performing this task.

Using the CSV-processing tools from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bash
$ csvsql -I --query "SELECT * FROM file WHERE \`Date of birth\` <= date('now', '-1 year')" file
Index,User Id,First Name,Last Name,Date of birth,Job Title
1,9E39Bfc4fdcc44e,"new, Diamond",Dudley,06 Dec 1945,Photographer
3,32C079F2Bad7e6F,Ethan,Hanson,08 Mar 2014,Actuary
```

This delegates the date parsing and any date computation to a database backend (SQLite).

Note that the output only quotes the fields that need quoting.  If you want quoting of *all* fields, pass the result through `csvformat -U1` (another csvkit tool).

EDIT: Note that the improperly quoted field `"Dudley (aka "dud")"` in the updated question will be transformed into `"Dudley (aka dud"")"""` by the csvkit tools (not shown here).

---

Without the csvkit tools and only using SQLite: Load the data directly from the CSV file and query it.  SQLite contains a CSV-aware reader and writer, so we can rest assured that the data will be appropriately quoted.

```bash
rm -f data.db
sqlite3 data.db \
    '.headers on' \
    '.mode csv' \
    '.import file mytable' \
    "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE \`Date of birth\` <= date('now', '-1 year')"
```

On my system (fanless "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz"), this takes about 0.75s for 100k records, of which 0.3s are used for building the SQLite database.  For 1M records, this takes just under 7 seconds, of which 4 are used for building the database.  For 10M lines, the operation takes about 1 minute 15 seconds, of which 45 seconds was used to build the database.

EDIT: Note that the improperly quoted field `"Dudley (aka "dud")"` in the updated question will be changed to the properly quoted field `"Dudley (aka ""dud"")"` by the SQLite CSV reader/writer (not shown here).

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```bash
$ mlr --csv filter 'strptime(${Date of birth}, "%d %b %Y") < "'$(date -d '-1 year' '+%s')'"' file
Index,User Id,First Name,Last Name,Date of birth,Job Title
1,9E39Bfc4fdcc44e,"new, Diamond",Dudley,06 Dec 1945,Photographer
3,32C079F2Bad7e6F,Ethan,Hanson,08 Mar 2014,Actuary
```

It's [`strptime()` function](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/date-time-examples/#how-can-i-filter-by-date).

If we want to change format of date after this command then the following command may be used:

```bash
$ mlr --csv filter 'strptime(${Date of birth}, "%d %b %Y") < strptime("'$(date -d '-1 year' '+%F')'","%F"); ${Date of birth} = strftime(strptime(${Date of birth}, "%d %b %Y"), "%F")' file
Index,User Id,First Name,Last Name,Date of birth,Job Title
1,9E39Bfc4fdcc44e,"new, Diamond",Dudley,1945-12-06,Photographer
3,32C079F2Bad7e6F,Ethan,Hanson,2014-03-08,Actuary
```

The [`csvsql` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/756774/469418) changes date format if used without `-I` or `--no-inference` option.

Answer (score -1):

```
IFS=$'\n'
lyear_old_sec=$(date -d "1 year ago" +%s)
echo '"Index","User Id","First Name","Last Name","Date of birth","Job Title"'
for i in $(cat sup.txt|awk 'NR>1')
do
dat_de=$(echo $i | awk -F "," '{print $(NF-1)}'|sed 's/"//g')
date_de_second=$(date -d "$dat_de" +%s)
if [[ $date_de_second -lt $lyear_old_sec ]]
then
echo $i
fi
done
```

Comment: markp-fuso’s comment on your deleted answer still applies here.